# Is there a <Do-nothing> kind of action in the EXPECT_CALL of Gmock?

Tags: unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

The SUT is calling an external library for which an EXPECT_CALL is defined. 
I want to only do something when the function is called for the first time and ignore doing anything the other time (but check that it's called twice); and vice versa.. i.e. do nothing the first time it is called and something the second time it is called.

```
// Code for the Expect Call  
EXPECT_CALL(*mock_ptr, some-function(_,_)) .Times(2) .WillOnce(action1)
.WillOnce(do-nothing);

// SUT call
ASSERT_NO_THROW(sut_function(arg1, arg2));
```

Ignoring the second (do-nothing) WillOnce, I am getting a Gmock warning like:

> GMOCK WARNING: test_blah-blah.cpp:321: Too few actions specified in
>   EXPECT_CALL(*mock_ptr, some-function(*,*))... Expected to be called
>   twice, but has only 1 WillOnce(). GMOCK WARNING:
>   test_blah-blah.cpp:321: Actions ran out in EXPECT_CALL(*mock_ptr,
>   some-function(*,*))... Called 2 times, but only 1 WillOnce() is
>   specified - returning directly.

What action do I give in the do-nothing part to not get this warning?
some-function is a void returning function.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// Code for the Expect Call  
EXPECT_CALL(*mock_ptr, some-function(_,_)) .Times(2) .WillOnce(action1)
.WillOnce(Return());

// SUT call
ASSERT_NO_THROW(sut_function(arg1, arg2));
```

Adding **Return()** for the second(or the first) .WillOnce solved the problem. Referred to the [cheatsheet](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/cheat_sheet.md#actions-actionlist) in github to find the matching action.